Calculating Composite Scores From an SPSS-Tuned Stata-Turning R Researcher
I am looking into how to make composite sum and average scores in R. It appears that most people use base::rowMeans and base::rowSums. I also know that other options exist (e.g., psych::scoreItems) to create composite scores. All of these options require that the inpute variables be numeric, which requires changing items comprising Likert scales from factors or ordered factors to numeric variables. I understand that the numeric values assigned to factor variable levels in other statistical programs are completely arbitrary and used mainly as a way to "tag" specific categories. However, the creation of so many extra variables (even if you delete them right after) worries me—even when putting their creation in the same pipeline as, for example, base::rowSums. Is there really no way to make a composite score out of factor variables where you can also tell R the scale that should be applied across items so that it treats the factor variable as numeric? I'm thinking of factor(x, levels = levels, labels = labels) as a potential analog.
I tried looking into other packages and whatnot, but have kept coming up dry.
Thank you for any insight!

Depends on what you have. If the values already represent numbers free from characters you can use the usual method.
Consider this data
> dat
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  10 10 50 30 20
2  50 50 50 20 30
3  10 40 50 40 10
4  10 20 40 40 50
5  20 20 20 20 20
6  40 30 40 50 20
7  20 10 30 40 20
8  20 10 20 50 40
9  10 30 10 40 30
10 40 40 20 20 50

where
> str(dat)              
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ X1: Factor w/ 5 levels "10","20","30",..: 1 5 1 1 2 4 2 2 1 4
 $ X2: Factor w/ 5 levels "10","20","30",..: 1 5 4 2 2 3 1 1 3 4
 $ X3: Factor w/ 5 levels "10","20","30",..: 5 5 5 4 2 4 3 2 1 2
 $ X4: Factor w/ 5 levels "10","20","30",..: 3 2 4 4 2 5 4 5 4 2
 $ X5: Factor w/ 5 levels "10","20","30",..: 2 3 1 5 2 2 2 4 3 5

Simply put the method in a function, use it in sapply then apply rowMeans or whatsoever.
> f2n <- \(f) as.integer(levels(f)[f])
> xvars <- c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5")
> transform(dat, score=rowMeans(sapply(dat[xvars], f2n)))
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 score
1  10 10 50 30 20    24
2  50 50 50 20 30    40
3  10 40 50 40 10    30
4  10 20 40 40 50    32
5  20 20 20 20 20    20
6  40 30 40 50 20    36
7  20 10 30 40 20    24
8  20 10 20 50 40    28
9  10 30 10 40 30    24
10 40 40 20 20 50    34

More complicated if they'd include strings but things like the following is possible.
> y
[1] very low    low         neutral     somewhat hi hi         
Levels: very low low neutral somewhat hi hi
> f2n2 <- \(f, a=0) as.integer(f) + a
> f2n2(y, -3)
[1] -2 -1  0  1  2


Data:
set.seed(42)
dat <- replicate(5, sample.int(5, 10, replace=TRUE)*10) |> data.frame()
dat[] <- lapply(dat, factor, 1:5*10)
> y <- factor(c('very low', 'low', 'neutral', 'somewhat hi', 'hi'), 
+             levels=c('very low', 'low', 'neutral', 'somewhat hi', 'hi'))

